# cambiar color de placeholder="Segundo Nombre"

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, color

como puedo cambiar el campo del forms de bootstrap  especificamente el placeholder de color  blanco

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes darle estilo al seudoelemento `placeholder`.

```
#input_id::placeholder {
  color:white;
}
```

Pero [esa especificación no es estándar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::placeholder) y sólo funcionará en navegadores recientes. (Chrome 57+, Firefox 51+, Opera 44+ y Safari 10.1+)

Para proveer compatibilidad con versiones anteriores (y con Internet Explorer o Edge), tendrás que darle estilo con prefijo para cada navegador:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder  /* Chrome, Opera ySafari */
::-moz-placeholder  /* Firefox 19+ */
:-ms-input-placeholder  /* IE 10+ y Edge */
:-moz-placeholder  /* Firefox 18- */
```

```css
#formGroupExampleInput {
  background-color:red;
  width:300px;
  color:white;
}

#formGroupExampleInput::placeholder {
 color:white;
}

#formGroupExampleInput::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: white;
}
#formGroupExampleInput::-moz-placeholder {
  color: white;
}
#formGroupExampleInput:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: white;
}
#formGroupExampleInput:-moz-placeholder {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="form-group">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Primer Nombre</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Primer Nombre">
  </div>
```

Probablemente quieras que el placeholder sea ligeramente más oscuro para diferenciarlo del texto ingresado.

Answer (score 2):

```html
    <html>
      <head>
      <style>
          input{
            background: skyblue;
          }
          
          #pnombre::placeholder {
            color: blue;
          }
          
          #snombre::placeholder{
            color: white;
          }
      </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <form>
          <input type"text" id="pnombre" placeholder="primer nombre">
          <input type"text" id="snombre" placeholder="segundo nombre">
        </form>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Solo coloca:

```html
  <html>
      <head>
      <style>
          #pnombre {
            background-color: blue;
          }
          
          #snombre{
           background-color: white;
          }
      </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <form>
   <input type"text" id="pnombre" placeholder="primer nombre"> 
          <input type"text" id="snombre" placeholder="segundo nombre"> 
        </form>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el pseudo-selector de CSS placeholder

```
::placeholder{
color: white;
}
```

```css
input{
background-color: orange;
color: white;
}

::placeholder{
color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" placeholder="hola mundo">
```

Saludos